# I want to capture only the first match occurrence

Tags: regex, perl

I am facing an issue where i'm trying to pull a specific format address from a given string using perl and regex. I want to be able to capture only the first occurrence of the match, however, it keeps on having multiple matches. This prevents me from pulling the first occurrence from the string as I can't seem to figure out how to refer to the first match using perl.

Regex:

```
((\d+[A-z]?(\s+\d\/\d)?|lot\s+\d+[A-z]?|apt\s+\d+[A-z]?)\s+[A-z]+\s+[A-z]+(\s+(avenue|street|road|drive))?)?
```

String:

> 27 MAIN STREET PO BOX 85 MAY PEN

Perl function:

```
sub hashaddress($)
{
    my $string = shift;

    if ($string =~ /\s?((\d+[A-z]?(\s+\d\/\d)?|lot\s+\d+[A-z]?)\s+[A-z]+\s+[A-z]+(\s+(avenue|street|road|drive))?)?/gi)
    {
        $string =~ /\s?((\d+[A-z]?(\s+\d\/\d)?|lot\s+\d+[A-z]?)\s+[A-z]+\s+[A-z]+(\s+(avenue|street|road|drive))?)?/gi;
        $string = $1;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

The perl function returns "85 MAY PEN" when what I want is "27 MAIN STREET" which is the first match.

Comment: change `/gi` to `/i`

Comment: The `/g` in scalar context continues to search in the string from the position of the previous match, every next time it's called.  So that `while (/.../g)` allows you to hop over the matches in the string, one at a time. But you normally don't want that in an `if` condition (which imposes the scalar context).  Now, I don't see how that affects your result here (it doesn't work that way across function calls) but that `/g` can only hurt,

Comment: "_I don't see how that affects your result here_" -- wait, I do see it: you regex runs in the `if` condition, and then inside the body, again!  So the run inside the body continues from where the previous one (in the condition itself) stopped, and thus matches the next time in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the [A-z] class.
By shaving down the regex a bit, you could resolve it to this:

```
sub hashaddress
{
    my ($string) = @_;

    if ( $string =~ /(?i)((\d+[a-z]?(\s+\d\/\d)?|lot\s+\d+[a-z]?)\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+(\s+(avenue|street|road|drive))?)/ ) {  
        return $1;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Regex info:

```
 (?i)                          # Case insensitive
 (                             # (1 start)
      (                             # (2 start)
           \d+ [a-z]? 
           ( \s+ \d / \d )?              # (3)
        |  lot \s+ \d+ [a-z]? 
      )                             # (2 end)
      \s+ [a-z]+ \s+ [a-z]+ 
      (                             # (4 start)
           \s+ 
           (                             # (5 start)
                avenue 
             |  street
             |  road
             |  drive 
           )                             # (5 end)
      )?                            # (4 end)
 )                             # (1 end)
```